# MCU to MCU communication over UART

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, programming

What would be the best way to send the following information from one MCU to another?

Now I'm just sending the sentence over as is eg. Serial.print(sentence in here)

Example sentence: 1306,60.123456,50.123456,23.765382,40.897558,245,85,20.3,5,65,1500,0.9

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends actually on your requirements what is 'best'.

If (transmission) speed is an issue, there are mainly some things you can do to improve this:

1. Increase the transmission speed (this depends on the distance of the wires and the noise).
2. Decrease the start/stop bits (this reduces the certainty the values will arrive ok)
3. Pack your data (takes more processing time possibly, and more programming work, but can be faster).

About the third option: since you are mostly sending values, you can make some improvements. So you can send them as float (by sending the float data, with the length of sizeof(float)). However, note there could be inaccuracies in the last digit.

Comment: Well I'm now at 9600baud and what I want to achive is less air time. How would one pack the values?

Comment: For example like I said, instead of serial.print, send it as floats

Comment: using Serial.print(floatVariable);

Comment: And boost the serial speed to 115200, will be 12x faster.

Comment: @CrossRoads if the noise/distance allows it, that's an easy improvement